# Cut a string- Catch: There is file with same name as string in the same path

Tags: sed, cut

Input

```
/in/archive/ABC/20140111_ABC_018_PART_001.dat
```

Desired Output:

```
20140111_ABC_018_PART_001.dat
```

Command used:

```
cut -d/ -f4 "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat"
```

Problem:

Its actually opening the file `20140111_ABC_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_018.dat` in the path `/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/` and displaying the result from file.

Comment: `basename /in/archive/ABC/20140111_ABC_018_PART_001.dat`

Comment: Or `fn="/in/archive/ABC/20140111_ABC_018_PART_001.dat"; echo "${fn##*/}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1. `basename` as Stephane suggested

   ```
   $ basename /1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat
   20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat
   ```

   `basename` is part of `coreutils`and simply strips the path from file names.
2. `awk`

   ```
   $ printf "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat" | 
      awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
   ```

   The `-F` option to `awk` defines the field separator. So,we set that to `/`and then print the last field (`$NF`).
3. `cut`

   ```
   $ printf "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat" |  
      cut -d '/' -f 6
   ```

   `-d` is the field separator and `-f 6` tells `cut` to only print the 5th field.

   This is a very limited approach though, since it requires you to know the number of fields in advance. A better way would be to use `rev` (which reverses it's input) to make the last field first, then `cut` to get the 1st field and then `rev` to get it back the way it was:

   ```
   $ printf "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat\n" | 
      rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
   ```
4. Perl

   ```
   $ printf "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat\n" |
      perl -pe 's/.+?([^\/]+)$/$1/;'
   ```

   The `-p` flag tells `perl` to print each input line after executing whatever script is given as `-e`. In this case, we simply tell `perl`to replace everything up to the longest stretch of non-`/` characters. Since this is Perl, there are many ways of doing this:

   ```
   $ printf "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat\n" | 
      perl -F/ -ane 'print $F[$#F]'
   ```

   The `-a` flag tells`perl`to behave like `awk`, it will automatically split each input line into the `@F` array. So,we set the field delimiter to `/` with `-F` and then print the last element of the array `($F[$#F]`). The `-n` causes `perl` to loop over it's input line by line.
5. `grep`

   ```
   $ printf "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat" | 
     grep -Po '[^/]+$'
   ```

   The `-P` activates [PCREs](http://www.pcre.org/) and the `-o` means "only print the matched string". So, we tell `grep` to look for the longest string of non-`/` up to the end of the input string (`$`).
6. shell

   ```
   $ foo="/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat";     
   $ printf "${foo##*/}\n"
   ```

   This takes advantage of the shell's string manipulation abilities. Specifically, the construct `${var##pattern}` will delete the longest match of `pattern` from the front of `$var`. So,`##*/`means delete everything until the last `/`.
7. `sed`

   ```
   $ printf "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat\n" | 
      sed 's/.*\///'
   ```

   `sed` will substitute everything up to the last `/`.

Comment: For the shell answer, doing `${foo##*/}` is defined in POSIX, the regex syntax isn't.

Comment: @Patrick thanks, so is the regex (or is that a glob?) a bash thing?

Comment: yes. many shells have it, so it's still fairly portable, just not a standard.

Comment: @Patrick fair enough, I added the `##` choice.

Comment: You can also drop the `tail` on the grep solution by doing `grep -Po '[^/]+$'`

Comment: @Patrick huh, should have though of that one, answer edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should `echo` the string into `cut`:

```
echo "/1a/ftproot/archive/ABC/20140111_PR1_018_SALESDOC_ITEM_001.dat" | cut -d/ -f6
```

(note that the field # is 6)

But Stephane's comment using `basename` is a better way to do that.

Comment: Note that for arbitrary data, [you should not use `echo` but `printf` instead](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22565). Also note that `cut` cuts the fields of each line of input, so it can't be used for arbitrary filenames as filenames can be made of several lines.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thank you. Should I delete my answer or update? I think what is still good is that it explains why things went wrong the way Rakesh did.

Comment: Yes.. Actually I was using this in shell script.. and it did not work... I had to use awk and print

Comment: display=$(echo ${file} |awk -F"/" '{print $6}')  .. here $file holds the string i want to edit.

Comment: Like Stephane wrote, you will have problems if the filename has newlines. Important is that cut does not take a commandline parameter as sting but if a parameter is there it is used as a filename.